# Security Risk or Not?

Tags: tor-browser-bundle, onion-services, security

Given the server foot-printing that MIT has recently discovered, and the fact that we know that they have been found to be in cahoots with at least one intelligence service (i.e. The FBI) Whats to say then that they aren't ongoing in their escapades? And further, given MIT's methodology of rogue nodes, whats to say that several intel services of various countries don't act in concert, providing part of the necessary rogue nodes in order to pull a sibyl / traffic confirmation attack, or any other theoretical attacks, for that matter, by simply sharing information, thus allowing the rogue nodes to appear less suspicious?

and yet Tor doesn't appear to have any defense against this sort of thing. It would seem to me that the best thing to do would to be to block government agencies from using Tor all together, but yet this may be interpreted as some to go against Tor's anti-censorship mission.

What do you think about this? Is Tor doing enough to protect it's users, or does it seem the whole concept needs to be overhauled?

Comment: How would you block government agencies from using Tor anyway..?

Answer (score 0):

> and yet Tor doesn't appear to have any defense against this sort of thing. It would seem to me that the best thing to do would to be to block government agencies from using Tor all together, but yet this may be interpreted as some to go against Tor's anti-censorship mission.

The design of Tor is such that you don't *have* to trust node operators - no one node in the circuit has enough information to perform deanonymizing.

The concern is rather when an attacker owns a large part of the overall network, which is why the past few years [there's been a push for more nodes](https://blog.torproject.org/blog/turning-funding-more-exit-relays) and there are [metrics to help watch these things](https://metrics.torproject.org/bubbles.html).